# CakePHP: Can I ignore a field when reading the Model from the DB?

Tags: cakephp

In one of my models, I have a "LONGTEXT" field that has a big dump of a bunch of stuff that I never care to read, and it slows things down, since I'm moving much more data between the DB and the web app.

Is there a way to specify in the model that I want CakePHP to simply ignore that field, and never read it or do anything with it?

I really want to avoid the hassle of creating a separate table and a separate model, only for this field.

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer because I doubt it's a great solution for you, but if worst comes to worst you could always create a custom View of that table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @SpawnCxy said, you'll need to use the `'fields' => array(...)` option in a `find` to limit the data you want to retrieve. If you don't want to do this every time you write a `find`, you can add something like this to your models `beforeFind()` callback, which will automatically populate the `fields` options with all fields except the longtext field:

```
function beforeFind($query) {
    if (!isset($query['fields'])) {
        foreach ($this->_schema as $field => $foo) {
            if ($field == 'longtextfield') {
                continue;
            }
            $query['fields'][] = $this->alias . '.' . $field;
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

---

Regarding comment:

That's true… The easiest way in this case is probably to unset the field from the schema.

```
unset($this->Model->_schema['longtextfield']);
```

I haven't tested it, but this should prevent the field from being included in the query. If you want to make this switchable for each query, you could move it to another variable like `$Model->_schemaInactiveFields` and move it back when needed. You could even make a Behavior for this.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, I wasn't able to test this before. This is a great idea, and it's in fact the closest to what I had in mind. However, the problem I'm getting with it is that explicitly specifying all the fields from this model makes the fields from the "related" models not be queried. In other words, I lost the data I was bringing through "belongsTo" relationships. Any ideas on how to fix that part?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Daniel That's true… See updated answer for a different approach.

Comment: Awesome, the unset() solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Modifying `_schema` is a nice trick, thanks a lot! Needed this for something a bit different, but worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm on v2.6 and when I try this from the beforeFilter of the controller I get: `Indirect modification of overloaded property Model::$_schema has no effect ` Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The parameter `fields` may help you.It doesn't ignore fields but specifies fields you want:

```
array(
'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'Model.field2'), //list columns you want
)
```

You can get more information of retrieving data in the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data) .

**Another idea**:

Define your special query in the model:

```
function myfind($type,$params)
{
     $params['fields'] = array('Model.field1','Model.field2',...);
     return $this->find($type,$params);
}
```

Then use it  in the controller

```
$this->Model->myfind($type,$params);
```

Comment: Do you know whether there is any way to set this list of fields as the "default" for the model every time it's read?
Because i'm querying it in dozens of places, and i wouldn't want to have to specify the long list of fields in each and every place.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Also try containable behaviour will strip out all unwanted fields and works on model associations as well.
 [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable)

```
class Post extends AppModel { <br>
    var $actsAs = array('Containable'); <br>
}
```

where Post is your model?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a beforeFilter function in your Table and add a select to the query

Excample:

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query){

$protected = $this->newEntity()->hidden;

$tableSchema = $event->subject()->schema();

$fields = $tableSchema->columns();
foreach($fields as $key => $name){
    if(in_array($name,$protected)){
        unset($fields[$key]);
    }
}
$query->select($fields);

return $event;
```

}

In this excample I took the hidden fields from the ModelClass to exclude from result.

Took it from my answer to a simular question here : [Hidden fields are still listed from database in cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226293/hidden-fields-are-still-listed-from-database-in-cakephp-3/40801763#40801763)