# Hidden fields are still listed from database in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am getting the records from my database in two different points, using "get" and "find" methods. The problem is that when I am using "get", "first" or "last" the hidden fields aren't displayed (Its ok), but when I am using "find" they are still there.

```
<?php
//My Plugin in /plugins/Comunica/Files/src/Model/Entity/File.php
namespace Comunica\Files\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class File extends Entity
{
  protected $_hidden = ['password'];
  protected $_virtual = ['protected'];

  protected function _getProtected(){
    return empty($this->_properties['protected']) ? false : true;
  }
}
```

The Call Method:

```
<?php
    $this->Files->find()->toArray();
```

Again. It is right when calling just one record (first, last, call), It's just wrong when trying with method "find". Any one knows how to solve this?

Comment: you are mixing somehow hidden and virtual fields.. the topic says hidden fields - I posted a possible solution for that, but I'm not sure if your problem is also related to the virtual field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer for this problem. The find returns an object that owns the entities of every result, so that you can convert them by using the "findAll" method inside the table's class.

```
<?php
//My Plugin in /plugins/Comunica/Files/src/Model/Entity/File.php
namespace Comunica\Files\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Query;//Include this class to manipulate the results

class File extends Entity
{
  protected $_hidden = ['password'];
  protected $_virtual = ['protected'];

  protected function _getProtected(){
    return empty($this->_properties['protected']) ? false : true;
  }

 //New formatation code
  public function findAll(Query $query, array $options)
  {
    return $query->formatResults(function ($results) {
      return $results->map(function($row) {
          $row['upload_date'] = $this->dateTimeConvert($row['upload_date']);
          return $row->toArray();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The only line that solves your problem is "return $row->toArray();" because hidden fields are excluded for results in array and json format - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties

Comment: Yap. This is it. It's easier doing that inside method findAll.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

My main aim was to exclude hidden fields by default and have a way to explicitly get Entitys including hidden fields if I need them.

ModelsTable.php

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query){

    //ATTENTION: if password field is excluded we have to bypass for Auth-Component to work
    if(array_key_exists('password',$_REQUEST)){
        return $event;
    }

    $protected = $this->newEntity()->hidden;

    $tableSchema = $this->schema();

    $fields = $tableSchema->columns();
    foreach($fields as $key => $name){
        if(in_array($name,$protected)){
            unset($fields[$key]);
        }
    }
    $query->select($fields);

    return $event;
}
```

Model.php

```
protected $_hidden = [
    'password',
    'otherSecret'
];

protected function _getHidden(){
    return $this->_hidden;
}
```

To receive hidden fields you can simple add ->select('password') to your query, but to make it more nice I added a custom finder

ModelsTable.php

```
public function findSecrets(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $tableSchema = $this->schema();
    $fields = $tableSchema->columns();
    return $query->select($fields);
}
```

Now you can build a query like this to receive Entity including hidden fields:

ModelsController.php

```
$secretModels = $this->Models->find()->find('secrets');
```

or whatever query you loke, simply add the custom finder
NOTE: is does not work with ->get($id) so you have to use ->findById($id)->find('secrets')->first()

I'm happy to know what you think about this solution or what you would change - feel free to commend :-)